# How can i display a particular product?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to display a particular product by clicking on it from the list

```
<ul>
    <% products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>

        <a href="<%= products_path(@product) %>"><%= product.title %> .   </a>
        <br/>

    </tr>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Expected results should be `products/1` but the result is `products.1` and should displays a list of products

Comment: show your config/routes.rb and output of `rake routes`

Comment: Perhaps try `product_path` instead of `products_path`?

Comment: If your routes used "resources :products" , then you can use simply <%= link_to "Product" , @product %>. No need to use any path. Just go with Product object.
Note : In controller method should be call "show".

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this

```
 <a href="<%= products_path(@product) %>"><%= product.title %> .   </a>
```

Use rails standard way

```
<%= link_to product.title, product_path(product)  %>
```

Comment: still the thing is same it shows product.id in url and shows a list of products

Comment: Do `rails routes -c products`  please add that result in question

Answer (score 0):

`products_path(@product)` should be `products_path(product)`

Comment: i did that but still no change

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do in this way instead of

```
<ul>
    <% products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>

        <a href="<%= products_path(@product) %>"><%= product.title %> .   </a>
        <br/>

    </tr>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

try

```
<ul>
    <% products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>

        <a href="/products/#{product.id}"><%= product.title %></a>
        <br/>

    </tr>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

but in rails way you can do

```
<ul>
    <% products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>

        <%= link_to product.title, product_path(product) %>

        <br/>

    </tr>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
        <% products.each do |product| %>
        <tr>

            <%= link_to product.title, product %>

            <br/>

        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
```

and in routes you shoud specify

```
resources :products
```

Comment: @SurenderSingh please accept the answer if it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your routes used **resources :products** , then you can use simply

> 

No need to use any path. Just go with Product object.

**Note :** In controller method should be call "show".